# What are the eight original Maken?

Tags: maken-ki

Okay I have searched forever but nothing has come up, what are the eight original maken, I would really like to know, I just can't find anything about them. thanks

Comment: Um... okay that's not fair everytime I seached something I thought it needed to start with MAKEN-KI etc

Comment: Futatsura. I WANT HIS RIGHTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you didn't find anything, because I found this [wiki link](http://makenki.wikia.com/wiki/Maken) as the first result when I Googled "8 original maken".

I'm not certain of spoilers since I haven't seen the series, but I've filtered out potential ones from the quoted info below.

> **"Original Eight"**
>
> **Murakumo** - Murakumo is a blade of light that is labelled as the blade
>   even the gods fear and it is ranked as the most destructive maken.
>
> **Habaya** - Habaya is a bow with arrows of light that pursue their
>   target.
>
> **Kamudo** - Kamudo is a gauntlet created by Yabiko Himegami on his
>   deification to battle his uncle. It was passed down
>   through the Oyama family line (as Yabiko was the ancestor of that
>   family).
>
> **Makaru** - It takes the shape of a earring that when brandished, can
>   call back a soul even from the underworld and resurrect the dead. It
>   can heal injuries, and allow the mind and soul to replenish at a speed
>   suitable for the host's powers.
>
> **Yata** - A zone-maken that reflects the owner's nature, and so changes
>   depending on the wielder.
>
> **Kanayago** - It takes the shape of a necklace that when activated, can
>   allow the user to condense all of the muscles in a person's body to
>   allow them to freely manipulate their bones and joints.
>
> **Furuno** - a Maken that takes the shape of a rapier that possesses the
>   ability to manipulate the friction coefficient of those that the user
>   cuts. It has a wide array of uses, such as changing the friction in
>   the air to make it heavy and restrict the movement of enemies along
>   with allowing the user to reduce their own friction, therefore
>   increasing their speed.
>
> **Futatsura** - a power-type maken that allows the user to forcibly steal
>   a right to anything. However, after activation, it cannot be used
>   again for half a month.

Comment: If you're looking for something deeper than simply the list of the eight original maken, then please update your question to be more specific.